# SQL Nested Where with Sums

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I've run into a syntax issue with SQL. What I'm trying to do here is add together all of the amounts paid on each order (paid each) an then only select those that are greater than sum of of paid each for a specific order# (1008). I've been trying to move around lots of different things here and I'm not having any luck.

This is what I have right now, though I've had many different things. Trying to use this simply returns an SQL statement not ended properly error. Any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated. Do I have to use DISTINCT anywhere here?

```
SELECT ORDER#,
    TO_CHAR(SUM(PAIDEACH), '$999.99') AS "Amount > Order 1008"
FROM ORDERITEMS 
GROUP BY ORDER# 
WHERE TO_CHAR > (SUM (PAIDEACH)) 
WHERE ORDER# = 1008;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of SQL regard the hash character (`#`) as the beginning of a comment. Others use double hyphen (`--`) and some use both. So, my first thought is that your `ORDER#` field is named incorrectly (though I can't imagine the engine would let you create a field with that name).

You have two `WHERE` keywords, which isn't allowed. If you have multiple `WHERE` conditions, you must link them together using boolean logic, with `AND` and `OR` keywords.

You have your `WHERE` condition *after* `GROUP BY` which should be reversed. Specify `WHERE` conditions before `GROUP BY`.

One of your `WHERE` conditions makes no sense. `TO_CHAR > (SUM(paideach))`: TO_CHAR() is a function which as far as I know is an Oracle function that converts numeric values to strings according to a specified format. The equivalent in SQL Server is [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

I'm guessing that you are trying to write a query that finds orders with amounts exceeding a particular value, but it's not very clear because one of your `WHERE` conditions specifies that the order number should be 1008, which would presumably only return one record.

The query should probably look more like this:

```
SELECT order,
    SUM(paideach) AS amount
FROM orderitems
GROUP BY order
HAVING amount > 999.99;
```

This would select records from the `orderitems` table where the sum of `paideach` exceeds 999.99.

I'm not sure how order 1008 fits into things, so you will have to elaborate on that.

Comment: +1. Since the column is called `Column#` I'm guessing that's the order number. Add a `where` clause for that and I think OP has his answer!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's supposed to be a subquery in there, which has somehow led to the two `where` clauses. I think it's supposed to find all `order#` with total `paideach` greater than whatever the total is for order 1008. The 999.99 is just the format mask for the output, not a value for comparison. (And `order#` is OK as a field name ir Oracle; `order` would not be as that's a reserved word).

Answer (score 1):

Other have commented on some of the things wrong with your query. I'll try to give more explicit hints about what I think you need to do to get the result I think you're looking for.

The problem seems to break into distinct sections, first finding the total for each order which you're close to and I think probably started from:

```
SELECT ORDER#, SUM(PAIDEACH) AS AMOUNT
FROM ORDERITEMS
GROUP BY ORDER#;
```

... finding the total for a specific order:

```
SELECT SUM(PAIDEACH)
FROM ORDERITEMS
WHERE ORDER# = 1008;
```

... and combining them, which is where you're stuck. The simplest way, and hopefully something you've recently been taught, is to use the `HAVING` clause, which comes after the `GROUP BY` and acts as a kind of filter that can be applied to the aggregated columns (which you can't do in the `WHERE` clause). If you had a fixed amount you could do this:

```
SELECT ORDER#, SUM(PAIDEACH) AS AMOUNT
FROM ORDERITEMS
GROUP BY ORDER#
HAVING SUM(PAIDEACH) > 5;
```

(Note that as @Bridge indicated you can't use the column alias, `AMOUNT`, in the having clause, you have to repeat the aggregation function `SUM`). But you don't have a fixed value, you want to use the actual total for order 1008, so you need to replace that fixed value with another query. I'll let you take that last step...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Oracle, and since it's homework I won't give you the answers, just a few ideas of what I think is wrong.

- select statement should only have one where statement - can have more than one condition of course, just separated by logical operators (anything that evaluates to true will be included). E.g. : `WHERE (column1 > column2) AND (column3 = 100)`
- Group by statements should after `WHERE` clauses
- You can't refer to columns you've aliased in the select in the where clause of the same statement by their aliased name. For example this won't work:

  `SELECT column1 as hello
  FROM table1
  WHERE hello = 1`
- If there's a `group by`, the columns you're selecting should be the same as in that statement (or aggregates of those). [This](http://www.thunderstone.com/site/texisman/summarizing_values.html) page does a better explanation of this than I do.